# AppEngine apps suddenly not able to connect to Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I had 2 GAE apps running wordpress and connecting to a single cloud SQL instance.

As of just a few minutes ago I'm guessing both apps can not longer connect.

My IP address is whitelisted and I'm able to connect to the SQL instance without an issue, it's just the App Engine instances that are having issues.

The error is the standard WordPress error "Error establishing a database connection"

We have not changed anything, maybe someone from Google can chime in?

So far I've tried rebooting the Cloud SQL instance which did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. The issue was that the MySQL user has to have a 'wp_user'@'localhost' account. You can't just have a 'wp_user'@'%' which seems odd because % is a wildcard so you'd think it would match everything. But somehow with the way GAE authenticates with Cloud SQL it needs to have the localhost user.

And because of the caching configuration the cause of this issue must be a change I made with the MySQL users a number of days ago. And the error only surfaced today. Gotta love caching.